# Show that $\sum\left|\eta_{j}\right|<\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $y=\left(\eta_{j}\right), \eta_{j} \in \mathbf{C}$, be such that $\sum \xi_{j} \eta_{j}$ converges for every $x=\left(\xi_{j}\right) \in c_{0}$, where $c_{0} \subset l^{\infty}$ is the subspace of all complex sequences converging to zero. Show that $\sum\left|\eta_{j}\right|<\infty$. I want to use uniform boundedness theorem to prove it but I completely don't know how to begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to prove this using UBP you can do it as  follows:

Let $T_N((\xi_j))=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} \xi_j\eta_j$. This defines a continuous linear functional on $c_0$ with $\|T_n||\leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} |\eta_j|$. To see that equality holds take $\xi_{j}=\frac{\overline{\eta_{j}}}{\left|\eta_{j}\right|}$ if $\eta_j \neq 0$ and $\xi_j=0$ otherwise. Then $\|(\xi_j)\|\leq 1$ so $\|T_N\| \geq T_N((\xi_j))=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} |\eta_j|$. It is given that $T_N((\xi_j))$ is convergent, hence bounded, for each fixed $(\xi_j)\in c_0$.  By UBP we have $\sup_N \|T_N\|<\infty$ which shows that $\eta_j \in \ell^{1}$.

Comment: why $\|T_n||\leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} |\eta_j|$?

Comment: $|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} \xi_j\eta_j | \leq \sup_j |\xi_j| \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} |\eta_j|$. By definition of norm of an operator we get $\|T_N\| \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} |\eta_j|$.